# Multiple Return Vlookup Horizontal match range with Vertical return range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, vba

I have binary data running in the horizontal direction: For example the match ranges look like:

Mike 0 1 0 0 0 1

Julie 1 1 0 1 1 0

Joe 1 1 1 0 0 0

And the return Range contains textual data:

Q1: What is the capital of NY?
Q2: What is the capital of Ohio?
Q3: What is the capital of Washington?
.
.
.

I need to match every occurrence of 1 with corresponding data that runs in the vertical direction. i.e. horizontal index corresponding with vertical index. I have found several instances where a multiple return vlookup was accomplished by using:

=IFERROR(INDEX(return_range,SMALL(IF((1=match_range),ROW(match_range)-1),ROW(1:1)),2),"")

However this isn't working. I assume it isn't working because it is meant for two vertical data sets. I have tried switching the "row" for "column" in the function, but didnt have any luck.

Also, the match range and return range are on different sheets.

The match range (in horizontal direction) is binary information on whether a question was answered correctly. The return range is the corresponding set of questions (in vertical direction). Therefore, the output would be an array:

Mike: Q2 Q6

Julie: Q1 Q2 Q4 Q5

Joe: Q1 Q2 Q3

[image][image]

How can this function be modified to accomplish this?

Comment: So what would the output look like?

Comment: The output would ideally be an array. Each row would contain cells where the return range was matched to the 1 of the match range for a single person.

Comment: No show me in the original post.  With the data above, what would the output be?

Comment: So I assume you have Q1,Q2,... as column headers?

Comment: I do not, the Q1, Q2, etc. in the above example is representing the actual text of the question. So a full sentence long. This is why the return range in the vertical direction.

Comment: Can you clarify precisely what you mean by "array" in the sentence "The output would ideally be an array"?

Comment: Each row (person) in the match data should produce a corresponding row in the result. Since the collection of match ranges is an array, the output should also be an array. But if you think about the output for just one person, the output would be a row. Does that make sense?

Comment: This just got a whole lot more complicates in that your items in column O are not unique.

Comment: No, there are unique names in columns before O, but I did not include them since they will remain unnamed. What you had seemed like it was going to help. But now it is deleted :(. It would be helpful if your formula could be written in generic form. i.e. match_range, return_range, identifier, etc.

Comment: The last section will work for you then.  As to general, that is why I included a photo to show the references.

Answer (score 0):

To get the correct row in an array that then can be used in other formula we use INDEX:

```
INDEX($A:$G,MATCH($I2,$A:$A,0),0)
```

This will return all the values in Column A through G in the row where the name matches that in I2.

It can be used as such in a INDEX/AGGREGATE Function:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$G$1,AGGREGATE(15,6, COLUMN(INDEX($A:$G,MATCH($I2,$A:$A,0),0))/(INDEX($A:$G,MATCH($I2,$A:$A,0),0)=1),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

[image]

---

My best guess as to your data set up:

Use a formula like this:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($I:$I,AGGREGATE(15,6, COLUMN(INDEX($A:$G,MATCH($K2,$A:$A,0),0))/(INDEX($A:$G,MATCH($K2,$A:$A,0),0)=1),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but the return data is not the column headers. It is a column of data, each cell containing the text of the question. How could this function be modified to handle this scenario. Thanks!

Comment: Again I am not sure what you want, please modify the table above, to show where the Q1,Q2,.. in your output is coming from.  I am a visual person.

Comment: And what are the numbers 15,6 corresponding to in the above function?

Comment: It is the small function, this allows us to use the small function without the need for Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Can you show a picture of the setup? I am not getting how you have it set up with words.

Comment: @user3887089 see edit for my best guess on your data set up.